# Labels cannot be moved although data-defined settings are active

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm trying to manually move labels but having some trouble. I'm trying to move the labels while in edit mode. I've added fields for x coordinate (all null), y coordinate (all null), rotation (all =0), and font-size (all =10). This makes the "move label" and "rotate label" buttons active, but when I click on the labels, no box around the label appears and it's impossible to move the label. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the labeling from labeling toolbar (NOT layer options - labels!)?

Answer (score 4):

We found recently the same behaviour occurs when layer's alias have special character like "à , é, ë.. etc". If this is your case, just rename layer to a simple name. 
I will create a new bug entry for this in hub.qgis.org.

Comment: I've tried your fix, but it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: I too would like to move some labels. Did you find a solution @Jake? Thanks.

Comment: @  Patty Jula:see my answer.

Comment: Is the behavior already documented as a bug? Otherwise I can also do it, because I just had this problem with ä and ü and would love to have it fixed...

Answer (score 3):

I assume that, you have not set enough space (field width)
for the coordinates of the label (these are real numbers). I think the moving is not possible because of this.I encountered the same problem once.

At any rate: This problem was solved in a current thread:
[How to add labels outside of features?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31484/how-to-add-labels-outside-of-features)
The new plugin automatically sets enough width in the field for the coordinates.
Moving should be possible then.